# Appium can’t get text from XCUIElementTypeStaticText

Tags: webdriver-io, appium-ios, xcuitest

I have simple XCUIElementTypeStaticText in my iOS app, but `getText()` doesn't work as expected it doesn't return text inside. Any tips&tricks or workarounds?

- Appium 2
- WebdriveriO - 8.3.2
- iOS: 15
- Node: v16.17.0

code:

```
const reportTitleName = await driver.$('~reportTitleName')
const reportName = await reportTitleName.getText() // not working
const reportName = await reportTitleName.getAttribute('value') // not working by any attribute: value or label

console.log('report name is: ', reportName ) // will print reportTitleName not content
```

Appium inspector:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well ...I had more issues to solve to make it work ... it was "only" this:

- **1. increase `snapshotMaxDepth`** so all elements are returned, default is 50

  - add to capability row: `appium:settings[snapshotMaxDepth]: 80`
- **2. switch off animations** (we had idle animation)

  - I was getting this error and timeouts: `Waiting up to 2s until com.myap is in idle state (including animations)`

### 3. do NOT add `accessibilityLabel` directly to `<Text>` component

if you do this:

```html
 <View>
   <Text accessibilityLabel="testID">TEXT_I_WANT</Text>
 </View>
```

snapshot will look somehow like this:

```html
<XCUIElementTypeOther ...>
  <XCUIElementTypeStaticText type="XCUIElementTypeStaticText" value="testID" name="testID" label="testID"/>
</XCUIElementTypeOther>
```

instead, add it to the parent component:

```html
 <View accessibilityLabel="testID">
   <Text>TEXT_I_WANT</Text>
 </View>
```

snapshot:

```html
<XCUIElementTypeOther type="XCUIElementTypeOther" name="testID" label="testID">
  <XCUIElementTypeStaticText type="XCUIElementTypeStaticText" value="TEXT_I_WANT" name="TEXT_I_WANT" label="TEXT_I_WANT"/>
</XCUIElementTypeOther>
```

After that, I had to get text from component by additional call:

```js
const element = await driver.$('~testID')
const elems = await element.$$('XCUIElementTypeStaticText')
const myTextElement = await elems[0].getText()
console.log(myTextElement)
```

What helped me to find such an easy way was to try all hints from this Appium issue thread: [App element tree (on IOS) not looking good #10654](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/10654).

NOTE: still open to better solution

Comment: #3 on this answer did the trick for me. I had the accessibility label on the <Text /> component which was overwriting the accessible value.

Answer (score 0):

The tilde in ~ `('~reportTitleName')` is used for finding elements by their accessibility id, which if set for the element, will appear above the ios class chain locator in Appium Inspector.

Try using `driver.$('-ios predicate string:label == "reportTitleName"')`. If there are other elements on the page that use this, you can narrow down the selection by adding the `AND value == "reportTitleName" AND name == "reportTitleName"` parameters.

Comment: ...but do you know how to get the text value from this element? This seems just to select the `reportTitleName` but not the text which is displayed to user